# Where should parameter validation take place to avoid code duplication

Tags: php, validation, oop

I'm wondering what the best practices/recommendations are here. Suppose I have a class providing functions manipulating an XMLElement.

```
class Foo
{
    private $data;

    public function setData(\SimpleXMLElement $data): void
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function getElement():string
    {
        return $this->data->element;
    }
}
```

The class is used in another class like so:

```
class Bar
{
    public function fooBar(string $data)
    {
        $xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($data);
        $foo = new Foo();

        $foo->setData($xml);
        echo $foo->getElement();
    }
}
```

Should both `setData()`and `fooBar()` validate their parameters?

Or is it OK if only `fooBar()` validates its parameter?

Or should the function calling `foobar()`validate its parameter?

Answer (score 1):

It actually depends on the specifics of your architecture. Lately I have begun favoring approach, that looks like this:

```
class User {
    // some code 
    public function setEmail(EmailAddress $email) { ....
}
```

Which is basically utilized as:

```
$bob = new User;
$bob->setEmail(new EmailAddress($param));
```

In this case the validation actually happens in the constructor of the `EmailAddress` class, that throws an exception, if you are attempting to instantiate it with something that is not a valid email address.

I think the general term for it is "value objects", but don't quote me on that. I have been borrowing this from people, who popularize the DDD approach to programming, even though I have serious doubts regarding DDD as a whole (it feels to me like a bit overkill, while introducing some "cross-layer confusion").

Comment: So the User class would rely entirely on the EmailAddress class to do the validation?

Comment: The idea would be that you can only create a valid `EmailAddress` entity. If you attempt to make an invalid one, it throws an exception. It boils down to this: validation of email address is **not** a responsibility of a `User` entity. It's and external *problem domain*.